# Proper initialization of UIViewControllers view frame

Tags: iphone

On my iPhone project I create the GUI with code. One question that passed my mind was, is it correct to write this:

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 460.0f)];
self.view = myView;
[myView release];
```

This would work on iPhone 4 right? Because I am not setting physical pixels when I write this, and on iPhone 4 it would be scaled automatically to 640 and 920? Or am I wrong.

I also wonder if there is a way of telling the main "view" that, "fill the container I belong to"? Because as this code is right now it wouldn't display correctly on iPad?

Help much appriciated:)

Comment: You can test in against the iPhone 4 in the simulator. Im pretty sure you need to set the view.contentScaleFactor = [UIScreen mainScreen].scaleFactor or something similar to that.

Comment: @Justin Meiners, That is wrong. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in iOS the view coordinate system is defined in points not pixels. The documentation sais, that if you work with UIKit then iPhone and iPod touch has a resolution of 320x480 *points* and the iPad has a resolution of 768x1024 points. 
If you work with OpenGL then you can have access to the real resolution in pixels, but if you only work with UIKit then you need to use only points.

to have your view "fill" the superview, you can do something like:

initWithFrame:self.view.superview.frame and set the autoresizing mask to ensure the view always fills the superview ;)

Hope this helps,
Moszi

Answer (score 2):

On the iPhone the values you give for x, y and width and height positions in a `CGRect` are in **points** not **pixels**. Points are relative to the scale factor. That is, given a known point width and height, you can determine, with the scale factor, how many pixels are on the screen by multiplying the width and height by the scale factor. However, this shouldn't matter to you. In iOS you always deal with points, not pixels when it comes to frames and bounds.

Comment: +1 Be interesting to see how they handle the inevitable next display size. (Can't see them neatly doubling the iPad display resolution any time soon, although I'd love to be wrong.) :-)

Comment: Thanks, however is it possible to add the "main view" to a viewcontroller and make it fill the whatever space is left? Because as my code is now it won't fill the entire iPad screen right?